# Azure LogicApp - Budget limit

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'd like to deploy two logicApps, having HTTP and E-Mail as triggers.
For budgets, I've only seen the option to get an alert, once limit is reached and I've few questions:

1. Is there any option to shut the logicApp off, once i reach a specified limit?
2. How do you protect your logicApps to prevent unwanted high bills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Powershell Script that stops a resource based on its cost and implement it in an Automation Runbook. Then you can schedule the Runbook to execute it periodically based on your needs.